# adding grid order total-refunded

Tags: magento-1.9

How to `add sales_flat_order` to the `collection` ?

```
     {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id'))
        ->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();

    }

        $this->addColumn('total_refunded', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total rembourse'),
    'index' => 'total_refunded',
    'width' => '25px',
    'align' => 'center',
));
```

I want to have `total_refunded` column in my grid from `sales_flat_order`

Comment: what you are trying to achive?

Comment: Add the amount refunded on the b / o sales orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with below `collection code:`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()
            ->join('sales_flat_order_address',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id'))
            ->join('sales_flat_order',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',
        array('total_refunded'))
        ->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Also, this `column code:`

```
$this->addColumn('total_refunded', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total remboursé'),
        'index' => 'total_refunded',
        'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',
        'width' => '25px',
        'align' => 'center',
    ));
```

**EDITED ANSWER:**

There is an issue while filtering your grid, and the issue is with `increment_id`.
compare your `add column code` with this `below code:`

```
$this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Credit Memo #'),
            'index'     => 'increment_id',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',
        ));
```

Comment: There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id WHERE (sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing') AND (increment_id LIKE '%33425%')

Comment: Check my edited answer section

Comment: Thanks, I do not have an increment column id in block / sales / order / grid.php

Comment: add this line `filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',` in your primary column.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I put a filter "date of purchase" I have a query error. I copy the complete file below

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id WHERE (sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing') AND (main_table.increment_id LIKE '%31186%') AND (created_at >= '2019-11-01 23:00:00' AND created_at <= '2019-11-30 22:59:59')

Comment: add `this` in `created_at` column:
`'filter_index'=>'main_table.created_at'`

Comment: pls mark my answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()
            ->join('sales_flat_order_address',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id'))
            ->join('sales_flat_order',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',
        array('total_refunded'))
        ->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
        'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
            'index'     => 'store_id',
            'type'      => 'store',
            'store_view'=> true,
            'display_deleted' => true,
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
        'index' => 'base_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id',
                        'data-column' => 'action',
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
    }

$this->addColumn('country_id', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Pays'),
    'index' => 'country_id',
    'width' => '25px',
    'align' => 'center',
    'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.country_id',
));
```

$this->addColumn('total_refunded', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total remboursé'),
        'index' => 'total_refunded',
        'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',
        'width' => '25px',
        'align' => 'center',
    ));

```
    $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}``
```